# Generate unique id in MariaDB

Tags: jpa, mariadb

I want to use JPA to generate unique id - 10 symbols long into MariaDB.

```
@Column
private String unique_id;
```

How I can configure MariaDB to auto generate unique id?

Comment: Is this about the '@Id' column ?

Comment: No - unique id value for table column.

Comment: A new feature in MariaDB 10.3 is the SEQUENCE. I don't have it installed perhaps a NEXTVAL in table definition or in a trigger could do the job. Other alternatives could be the expensive UUID function. In any case, you should have the JPA field with  ' @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)'

Comment: Do you know how I can generate into MariaDB 10 characters String using JPA?

Comment: Just an idea. Can you come up with your own java function generating these unique identifiers? You can do so perhaps by using another table in the database, or an Atomic value initialized during application startup. Is so you can use JPA lifecycle event methods as '@PrePersist' to update the value of the Entity before it's actually written to the DB.

Comment: I already found some example on the Internet but I want to generate 10 length long String into MariaDB using JPA configuration. It's very important to do this.

Comment: Spell out the characteristics that you want of the "unique id".  Then read about `AUTO_INCREMENT`, UUIDs, and `SEQUENCE`.